# Cannot see a switch user in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I use Windows 8 Home edition and I do not find the "Switch User" account that people seem to be seeing as shown in

http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-8/user-accounts-frequently-asked-questions

Infact when I press the window key and click on the icon against my username I only see the Lock Screen/Sign out

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Do you have more than one user account?

Comment: Yes I do have more than one user account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent software installation might have hidden the **Switch User** button on the lock screen. You can re-enable it by using either of the following methods:

### Method 1: Registry edit

1. Open **run** command and type `regedit`.
2. Navigate to the following:

   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
3. Modify the registry value of `HideFastUserSwitching` from 1 to 0. A value of 0 disables this setting, which allows Windows to display the **Switch User** button on the lock screen and in menus (e.g., where you sign out, shut down, etc.).
4. Log off and restart the machine.

### Method 2: Group policy fix (not available in Home edition of Windows 8)

1. Open **run** command and type `gpedit.msc`
2. Navigate to the following location

   > Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/AdministrativeTemplates/System/Logon
3. Double-click `Hide Entry Points for Fast User Switching` to bring up a dialog box to change policy setting.
4. Choose `Disabled` in the popup box. This will allow Windows to display the **Switch User** button on the lock screen and in menus (e.g., where you sign out, shut down, etc.).
5. Close the group policy editor, open **run** command and type `gpupdate /force` to have the change take effect.

Comment: When I type "Windows + Q" I see the run box and I typed "gpedit.msc" and nothing came up, have I missed something? I shall use the registry updating as the last resort.

Comment: @CalmStorm whats happening while u search for gpedit.msc which version you using for windows 8?

Comment: I use Windows 8 Home Edition and when I search for gpedit.msc I get a "No matching results" in the main pane.

Comment: @CalmStorm by default gpedit was not provided for home editions,maybe this tweak may help you from here http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/2847-73-enable-gpedit-windows-home-edition which will enable the gpedit

Answer (score 0):

I Faced the same issue when my password expired and I had to go to switch user to change the password - however could not find the switch user icon or option. 
Do you have your mouse connected ? For some strange reason, once I connected the mouse ( I dont use this machine too often ) - The switch user option appeared. You may want to try..

regards
Orjun