# Cannot Switch Users in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, login-screen, user-switching

Today, I decided to test some new software I'm developing on my PC under a non-admin account.

I've run into a huge problem, though: I'm unable to switch accounts! I have the Guest account enabled and have also created a test user (local account, standard user). Neither of them show up when clicking my profile in the upper-right corner of the Start screen. Windows doesn't seem to believe that those accounts exist anywhere besides the 'Manage Accounts' screen.

I'm very confused here. The *only* way I can even access the 'Switch User' function is by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> or via the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> menu. Once I click 'Switch User' there, it takes me to the sign-in screen, but only my account is listed. The small arrow to the upper left of my account picture - which is supposed to let you switch users - is not available.

It seems that this could possibly be a result of [fast user switching](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-enable-disable-fast-user-switching-in-windows-xp-and-windows-vista/) being disabled, but I'm not sure since I can't switch user accounts *anywhere*. I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro edition, so the group policy editor is not available to me. I've tried adding the registry entry manually to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: The group policy editor, `gpedit.msc`, is available for Windows 8.1 Pro (and regular Windows 8.1, too)...

Comment: Allow me to disgrace the name of "SuperUser" here. I obtained Windows 8.1 via DreamSpark, and I forgot that I'm using the standard edition. I'm 99% sure gpedit.msc is not available for Windows 8.1

Comment: Try it. I'm sure it works.

Comment: "*Allow me to disgrace the name of 'SuperUser' here*" We accept any kind of question with any situation, as long as it fits the rules outlined in the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/)

Comment: It may be a moot point anyway. I "borrowed" gpedit.msc, but the option to enable fast user switching was not even listed under my local policies. This answer describes what the available fix _should_ be: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/648858/cannot-see-a-switch-user-in-windows-8?rq=1)

Comment: I remember that Windows 7 and up no longer have that as an option and instead just make it an inherent part of the OS (i.e. it's on all the time ande can't be changed)